# The best way to connecting two applications on one machine?

Tags: wcf

WCF gives me a whole bunch of capabilities to connect two applications that are running on the same machine.

But which is the best one for my use case?

I want to develop a local application (server) which provides functionality to connect to a webserver. I want to connect from various Office application and WPF-applications to the local "server" (MVC) to send messages, files etc. to the webserver.

Is `System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream` the right way?

Comment: Surely you mean `NamedPipeBinding`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need not to dial with stream directly.

If your Office apps support this, the NamedPipe binding, mentioned by Aron, will be probably the best choice.

You can also use port sharing to allow both your services to re-use single port.